# Signal Initialization in Flash-Based FPGAs (e.g. Microsemi)

Tags: fpga

I've been looking through the Microsemi literature and I'm not seeing a clear answer to this question.  Is it possible to set registers in the Microsemi fabric to a non-zero initial condition on FPGA power-up?

Here's what I was able to find:

> When the VersaTile is used as an enable D-flip-flop, SET/CLR is
>   supported by a fourth input. The SET/CLR signal can only be routed to
>   this fourth input over the VersaNet (global) network. However, if, in
>   the user’s design, the SET/CLR signal is not routed over the VersaNet
>   network, a compile warning message will be given, and the intended
>   logic function will be implemented by two VersaTiles instead of one.

Does this still mean that I need to route a reset line to set the Flip-Flop?  I know that on LUT-based FPGAs like Xilinx, Altera, and Lattice, the registers can be initialized when the bitstream is loaded, without the need of a set/reset pulse.  This is a handy feature that I use often and I'm wondering if Microsemi supports it.

Comment: Do you have a test board with this chip? Can you instantiate 2 FFs one set to `0` and one to `1` and then connect the FFs to 2 LEDs? You should ensure that the second FF is not replaced by a NOT gate :).

Comment: Many FPGAs do not actually have this possibility but just imitate it using NOT-Gate-Push-Back, i.e. the interpretation of a register is inverted, the single reset-value is used and in- and outputs are inverted. In many cases this does not even add additional logic as it can be absorbed by neighbouring LUTs and therefore having two actually different reset-values would just be an unnecessary degree of freedom.

Comment: @Paebbels, sadly I do not have a Microsemi board.

Comment: @Russell: The application note [AC380- Internal Power-on Reset and Post Programming Reset Circuit for Flash-Based FPGAs App Note](http://www.microsemi.com/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=134599) is maybe relevant.